# WCF NetMsmq Security

Tags: wcf, security, claims-based-identity, adfs

I am trying to call a WCF service (netmsmq endpoint) which has been secured against ADFS. I need to open a channel with an issued token that resides in the application context.

The code below is my atempt to do that, however, I get the following exception:

> The signing token System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SamlSecurityToken has no
>   keys. The security token is used in a context that requires it to
>   perform cryptographic operations, but the token contains no
>   cryptographic keys. Either the token type does not support
>   cryptographic operations, or the particular token instance does not
>   contain cryptographic keys. Check your configuration to ensure that
>   cryptographically disabled token types (for example,
>   UserNameSecurityToken) are not specified in a context that requires
>   cryptographic operations (for example, an endorsing supporting token).

I am aware this error message is to do with [BearerKey](http://travisspencer.com/blog/2012/01/cryptographic-operations-are-r.html) tokens, however, the netMsmqBinding doesn't expose the property `binding.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.BearerKey;`

What to do? Is it even possible to call a netmsmq service with an issued token? It [seems](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84b1cfa9-6d00-47d6-9418-ca54a19148d0/can-i-use-wif-with-queued-wcf-endpoints?forum=Geneva) so.

```
    public string CallServiceQueue()
    {
        try
        {
            var binding = new NetMsmqBinding(NetMsmqSecurityMode.Message);
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.IssuedToken;

            var ep = new EndpointAddress("net.msmq://localhost/private/service/helloqueue.svc");

            var factory = new ChannelFactory<IHelloQueue>(binding, ep);
            factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
            factory.Credentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;
            factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "74 0A FE 19 E9 F0 53 9C 46 D9 F2 D6 56 A7 0C E8");

            var context = (BootstrapContext)((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).BootstrapContext;
            var channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(context.SecurityToken);

            channel.SayHello();

            ((IServiceChannel)channel).Close();

            return "Your message has been sent.";
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            return "Access denied.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```